# How to deal with multiple screen sizes when using html2pdf library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to print a pdf version of my webpage. I have set page breaks at certain points using `<div class="html2pdf__page-break"></div>`. This is provided by the html2pdf library. However, when a user minimizes the screen even a little bit the entire pdf gets messed up as some fields are cut in half at the end of the page. Is there a way for me to setup html2pdf to print the pdf as if it was for a default desktop size screen? Is there any other way for accounting for different sized screens?

Edit1:

The plugin I am using is html2pdf. To convert a webpage to a pdf and download it, all I need to do is On my HTML:

```
<body class="element-to-print">
```

On my scripts section

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
 html2pdf().from(element).save();
```

The problem is that I cannot set the page breaks if I do not know where the sections are on different screen sizes. When a user changes the size of browser window when browsing my site the location of div and section is going to change.

When a user hits

> ctrl +p

on google and prints a pdf of the page, it does not matter which screen size the use has. The output pdf always looks the same. I am looking to to do the same thing with html2pdf library.

Comment: make it pop open a new window containing the content you want to have saved, save it and then close the pop up

Comment: Popup's of a laptop is going to be bigger than the popup of a mobile. I will be in the same problem as I was before.

Comment: The reason printing from chrome or another web browser works fine is because the system is handling saving the pdf rather than a library within the code itself.

Comment: @greenn did you solve the issue?